# Class Class Method ruby

Tags: классы, функции, ruby, методы

Я раньше не пользовался классами, захотел разобраться.
Можно ли в `Ruby` сделать класс в классе?
Что то вроде этого:

```
class First
  def hi
    puts 'hello'
  end
  class Second
    def bye
      puts 'goodbye'
    end
  end
end
```

И после этого что бы я мог обращаться к функциям `hi` и `bye` вот так:

```
First.hi
First.Second.bye
```

Можно ли так сделать? И если можно, как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш пример правильный, но работает он немного не так, как Вы представляете. Во-первых метод `hi` - это метод экземпляра класса `First`. Соответственно сначала надо создать экземпляр класса:

```
f = First.new
```

а затем уже можно вызывать для этого экземпляра метод `hi`:

```
f.hi
```

Чтобы работал вызов `First.hi`, необходимо определить метод самого класса:

```
class First
  class << self
    def hi
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end
```

или

```
class First
  self.hi
    puts 'hello'
  end
end
```

Теперь о вложенных классах. Определить класс внутри класса можно. В Руби каждый класс является модулем. А модуль является коллекцией методов и констант. Небольшая ремарка, когда вы определяете класс

```
class Foo; end
```

на самом деле создаётся объект типа `Class` и присваивается глобальной константе `Foo`. Если Вы определяете класс в модуле, то новый объект типа `Class` присваивается константе следующего формата ModuleName::ClassName. Так как класс `First` является модулем, и если в нём определить новый класс `Second`, то новый объект типа `Class` будет присвоен константе `First::Second`. 
Исходя из этого метод `bye` экземпляра класса `Second`, определённого в классе `First`, можно вызвать, создав предварительно экземпляр класса `First::Second`:

```
s = First::Second.new
s.bye
```

При этом внутри класса `First`, класс `Second` будет доступен по своему имени, например

```
class First
  def hi
    puts 'hello'
  end

  def bye
    Second.new.bye
  end

  class Second
    def bye
      puts 'goodbye'
    end
  end
end
```

В вашем вызове

```
First.Second.bye
```

будет ошибка, так как в это случае интерпретатор будет пытаться вызвать метод `Second` класса `First`.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Но есть еще вопрос. Зачем использовать `.new?`

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html#method-i-new